# Style of tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to change style of table of contents which is given by \tableofcontents,
(say I do not want that much space between lines and some I want the subsections to be listed in one line).

How can I do that?

(So far I can only edit toc-file by hands, which is not a good solution.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer for almost all TOC, LOF, LOT, etc. customisations is first to see if you can achieve what you want using the [tocloft](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package. Nine times out of ten, you'll be able to.

Answer (score 3):

To complement @Geoffrey's answer, note also that if you use the `memoir` class, the `tocloft` is included (reproduced ?) and you can use the same functionalities. The memoir manual has a complete chapter about the customization of the ToC, LoF, LoT.