# Tableofcontents as actual table with borders and stuff

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

#### Details:

- I want my `\tableofcontents` to actually appear as table
- i am using latex
- i traced what the command `\tableofcontents` does, and in the end,
  i found that the `\contentsline` macro chain do not save the `\thechapter` and `\chaptername` as different entities
- ... so, the modification of it to table seems difficult to me atm
- this is also mentioned in the manual of package<sup>[[a]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6034/206969)</sup> [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) at [page 24](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf#page=24))

> For the purposes at hand it is generally impossible to treat the typesetting of
> a title and its number separately, as both are bundled into the <title> argument
> within \contentsline.

#### MWE

Minimum Working Examples (as asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551351/any-one-can-explain-me-how-to-add-zero-chapters-in-table-of-content#comment1392418_551351)):

##### Default:

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First sdddsssss %
        sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssss ssssssss sssssss %
        ssssssssss sssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssss ssssssss %
        sssssssssssss sssssssss}
\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image: Default tableofcontents]

#### Target

(well, somewhat! as the [package tabularray](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete), nice name, doesn't seem [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science) in its implementation of functions to me, so, i am still unable to properly define all the things in it, but this will *work*)

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

%\begin{tblr}{| m{1em} | m{9cm} | m{2cm} |}
\begin{tblr}{| c | m{9cm} | m{2cm} |}
    \hline
    \bfseries thechapter & \bfseries chaptername & \bfseries comments \\ 
    \hline
    1 & First sdddsssss %
    sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssss ssssssss sssssss %
    ssssssssss sssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssss ssssssss %
    sssssssssssss sssssssss & \\ 
    \hline
    2 & Second & \\ 
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wanted "tableofcontents"]

#### PS:

On the [orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science) of tabularray:

I wanted to specify following options:

- horizontal arrangement (l,c,r)
- vertical arrangement (t,m,b,h,f) 
  update: i think `t`,`m`,`b` concern with relative alignment of the specified base?lines of the columncells across their whole row; whereas `h`,`f` concern with the absolute alignment in individual cell
- columnwidth
- special vertical alignment for the header row
- row formatting for the header

Comment: yes, sorry for that, i was trying to keep it minimal for the default, but was testing the line auto wrapping for the target, and while posting it here, forgot to make those both consistent. I will sync this in the code example above. should i update the screenshot too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfectly imperfect solution I used to get the toc in a table was:

*(yes, changed format is intentional i.e. reduced the rules a bit, added chapter children and page numbers for completeness sake)*

```tex
\documentclass{report}

% Table spanning pages
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{ifthen}

% Vertically padded hlines or rules
% \usepackage{booktabs}

% Padded Rule
\newcommand{\prule}{\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}}

% Extract (.sty, \usepackage): Modify toc commands for table
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1 & }%\bfseries}
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\gdef\@contentsline@destination{#4}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{chapter}}{\\ \prule}{ \\ }
    #2 & #3 &
}
\newcommand{\mytoc}{
    \begin{longtable}{  p{5mm} | p{6.5cm} | p{1cm} | p{2cm}  }
        % \toprule
        \bfseries sr & \bfseries chaptername & \bfseries pg & \bfseries comments
        \input{\jobname.toc} \\
        % chktex "Command terminated with space" is wrong (VSCodium: LaTeX Workshop)
        % Do NOT use \prule{}
        \prule 
    \end{longtable}
}

\begin{document}

% Run this command to update the toc file, then recomment again
% \tableofcontents

\mytoc{}

\chapter{First sdddsssss %
    sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssss ssssssss sssssss %
    ssssssssss sssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssss ssssssss %
    sssssssssssss sssssssss}
\section{Child}
\section{Child}
\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image: Conditional Rule]

This is "perfectly imperfect" because:

- it works while nothing else did (hence perfect)
- <strike>indentation of sections need to be *re*-implemented too</strike>
- the packages dealing with toc modification like `bookmark` `etoc` etc likely won't work with this
- contents enteries no longer clickable/linked (`hyperref` package)

**Note 2023.05.14:**

- Disable auto "Clean" options in tex-related build tasks like in "LaTeX Workshop" extension in VSCodium
  *(honestly though, if compiling in TXS, then extensions TeXLab and vscode-pdf are enough, just disable this stupid latex-workshop extension with stupid `chktex`)*


  **old point:**
  though breeze in TeXStudio (TXS); but with `latexmk` and `chktex` in VSCodium, running `\tableofcontents` and commenting it out becomes arduous task. Tried with following inside `\mytoc` definition to avoid that, but none worked: `\makeatletter\@starttoc{toc}\makeatother` or [Generating .toc file without generating a ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66476/#66478)

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "never",
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.cleanAndRetry.enabled": false,
```

**Changes since original answer:**

- Fix (trailing vertical rule in end): Move the `\makeat*` pair outside the table
- Dev: Remove `@` using command, hence also the `\makeat*` pair
- New ([conditional](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#Conditionals)<sup>1</sup> hlines): `hline` before chapter (todo: "[logical or](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/)" with "part") to group children (*sections)
- New: Page column for completeness of answer for others
- New: `\prule` and `\mytoc` for ease of use

Any suggestions, bug fixes or improvements welcome

---

**Footnotes:**

<sup>[1]: I used the Wikibook pdf - which remains outdated. I later found via [LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/#comment9460_5896) that 'obsolete `ifthen` package' - This same question is also indirectly linked via footnotes in the Wikibook on web.</sup>

---

P.S.:
Aaaah, just found from [md-advanced-help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) that

- language tags for [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) on SE are prefixed with "lang", hence becomes `lang-<lang>`
- which's different than github/gitlab's `<lang>` tag :confused:
- so, `tex` tags were ignored, rather, the `lang-tex` tag seems to be specified across this tex.se site... :facepalm:

Also, don't change the "Edit summary" to enable appending the changes to previous revision if allowed. This "appension" is likely constrained, so, doesn't work always.

Comment: I can't help too much, but: (1) you shouldn't need a separate style file, just surround that portion with `\makeatletter/\makeatother`.  (2) `booktabs` abhors vertical lines in tables, and explicitly breaks them.